# Persistence of a variable through program restarts

Tags: javascript, node.js, persistence, discord.js

I'm a bit new to JavaScript and I was wondering, how do I have a variable in my program persist after I turn off the program and turn it back on again.

For example, if I have:

```
//Call package
var Discord = require("discord.js");
var caterpieBot = new Discord.Client();
var nextClubMeeting;

//Listener Event for recieved messages
caterpieBot.on("message", message =>
{
  var sender = message.author; // who sent the message
  var msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
  var prefix = "!" //command to interact with caterpieBot
  var tempMsg = msg;
  var splitMsg = tempMsg.split(":")


  if(splitMsg[0] === "CATERPIE, PLEASE SCHEDULE OUR NEXT CLUB MEETING FOR")
  {
      message.channel.send("Yes " + sender + ", I will schedule the next club meeting for: " + splitMsg[1])

      nextClubMeeting = splitMsg[1]; //I WANT "nextClubMeeting" TO //PERSIST ON RESTART!

  }
```

And I have the user change that number to `2` when the program is running. When I restart the program if I tried to print `userInputedNumber` it would return as `undefined`. How would I have my program remember that `userInputedNumber = 2` after it is restarted? (`2` would be whatever number the user inputted).

Comment: Browser or Node?

Comment: I'm using Node. I also edited the origional post to make it look more like my program. I'm programming a discord bot for my club. I snipped the important parts

Comment: The simplest way might be to write to a file system.  E.g. something like node-persist (https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist).  Or you can use a database like redis to keep data in memory.

Comment: I know in java you can do something like:                              BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("ClubMeetingInfo.txt")));
writer.write(nextClubMeeting);
writer.close();   : but is this possible in JS? that way i could just store the string in a .txt file and reset the variable to the string in the .txt each time the program starts

Answer (score 0):

Hm, you may need to setup a database to store that data. There are other ways of "persisting" data on the frontend where messages are being exchanged. Sessions are a looser way of doing so but this seems more of a user specific input related to that specific user. Perhaps you can route in MongoDB into your app and store it, and access it later whenever you need to?